# what is the best way to push an array of objects into an array

Tags: javascript, react-native

Here is the array of objects that is to be push to an array

```
  [{"a":11,"b":21},{"a":31,"b":41},{"a":10,"b":20}]
```

How to achieve this array below from the above

```
"array": [
    [
      [
        11,
        21
      ],
      [
        31,
        41
      ],
      
      [
        10,
        20
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: What do you mean by *best way*? We cannot help you unless you show us what you tried so far to do what you are asking here.

Comment: What would be the benefit to creating a 3D array instead of using the form that it's in now?

Comment: the api request asks this format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The **`map()`** method **creates a new array** populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

---

```js
var array1 = [{"a":11,"b":21},{"a":31,"b":41},{"a":10,"b":20}];

var array2 = [array1.map(item=>[item.a, item.b])];

console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Map it

```js
let arr = [{"a":11,"b":21},{"a":31,"b":41},{"a":10,"b":20}]
 
 let result = [arr.map(({a,b}) => [a,b])];
 
 console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use reduce to form an array and then Object.values to extract the object prop values for each sub array.

```js
const arr = [{
  a: 11,
  "b": 21
}, {
  "a": 31,
  "b": 41
}, {
  "a": 10,
  "b": 20
}];



const result = arr.reduce((acc, x) => {
  const values = Object.values(x);
  acc.push(values);
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log({
  array: result
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is push each element of B into A you can do `A.concat(B).`

If you want to make a new array with all the values your can

`c = ([]).concat(A,B)`

For your array of objects with values, you could

```
    c = []; for ( vals in b ) c.concat(Object.values(vals);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[].concat(array.map((val)=>Object.values(val)))
```

Comment: While your answer may be fine, it is always helpful to include a description of what your code does so everyone can follow along. Not everyone is necessarily on the same proficiency level.